# animate when area is visible by scrolling Jquery

Tags: jquery, animate.css

I am using [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/) to give some animations for divs when scrolling.
It is working, but the animation play when I start scrolling not when the animated area is visible.  Any ideas how can i play the animation when area is visible ?!
Following is my JavaScript code:

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
            if ( scroll) {
                $('.anim-left').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
                $('.anim-fade-right').addClass('animated flipInY');
            }
        });

        function getCurrentScroll() {
            return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wow.js will reveal animation with scrolling.

http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.